# Twitter sentiment analysis based on selected users

Tags: python, api, twitter, nltk, sentiment-analysis

I'm in need of some advice with my Twitter sentiment analysis. 
I'm trying to do a pretty common sentiment analysis, but not on random tweets from Twitter search, but on the tweets of selected users.

What I've tried so far, is that I read in this csv of the users. And then iterated over this list and then, user by user conducted this tweet analysis.
I'll put my write_tweets function here, just so it could get some feedback maybe :)

```
def write_tweets(users_df, file):
    # If the file exists, then read the existing data from the CSV file.
    if os.path.exists(file):
        df = pd.read_csv(file, header=0)
    else:
        df = pd.DataFrame(columns=COLS)
    #page attribute in tweepy.cursor and iteration
    for user in users_df[0]:
    #for user in users_list:
        print(user)
        #user = 'fion_li'

        try:
        #for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, screen_name=user, count = 1,tweet_mode="extended").items(22):
        for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, screen_name=user, count = 1,tweet_mode="extended").items(1):


            #print(status)
            new_entry = []
            status = status._json
            #print(to_datetime(status['created_at']))
            #print(status['full_text'])

            #csvFile = open(file, 'a' ,encoding='utf-8')

            if (to_datetime(status['created_at']) < startDate):
                 #print(to_datetime(status['created_at']))
                 #print(status['full_text'])

                continue


            ## check whether the tweet is in english or skip to the next tweet
            if status['lang'] != 'en':
                continue



           #tweepy preprocessing called for basic preprocessing
            #clean_text = clean(status['entities'])
            clean_text = clean(status['full_text'])


            #call clean_tweet method for extra preprocessing
            filtered_tweet=clean_tweets(clean_text)

            #pass textBlob method for sentiment calculations
            blob = TextBlob(filtered_tweet)
            blob_2 = TextBlob(filtered_tweet, analyzer=NaiveBayesAnalyzer())

            Sentiment = blob.sentiment
            Sentiment_2 = blob_2.sentiment

            #seperate polarity and subjectivity in to two variables
            polarity = Sentiment.polarity
            subjectivity = Sentiment.subjectivity

            positivity = Sentiment_2.p_pos
            negativity = Sentiment_2.p_neg


            #new entry append
            new_entry += [status['id'], status['created_at'],
                          status['source'],
                          #status['full_text'],
                          filtered_tweet, Sentiment,polarity,subjectivity, positivity, negativity, status['lang'],
                          status['favorite_count'], status['retweet_count']]

            #to append original author of the tweet
            new_entry.append(status['user']['screen_name'])

            try:
                is_sensitive = status['possibly_sensitive']
            except KeyError:
                is_sensitive = None
            new_entry.append(is_sensitive)

            # hashtagas and mentiones are saved using comma separted
            hashtags = ", ".join([hashtag_item['text'] for hashtag_item in status['entities']['hashtags']])
            new_entry.append(hashtags)
            mentions = ", ".join([mention['screen_name'] for mention in status['entities']['user_mentions']])
            new_entry.append(mentions)

            #get location of the tweet if possible
            try:
                location = status['user']['location']
            except TypeError:
                location = ''
            new_entry.append(location)

            try:
                coordinates = [coord for loc in status['place']['bounding_box']['coordinates'] for coord in loc]
            except TypeError:
                coordinates = None
            new_entry.append(coordinates)

            single_tweet_df = pd.DataFrame([new_entry], columns=COLS)
            #print(single_tweet_df)
            df = df.append(single_tweet_df, ignore_index=True)
            csvFile = open(file, 'a' ,encoding='utf-8')
        except Exception, e:
         pass
    #csvFile = open(file, 'a' ,encoding='utf-8')         
    df.to_csv(csvFile, mode='a', columns=COLS, index=False, encoding="utf-8")


write_tweets(users_list,  test_file)
```

Output would be a few indicators of sentiment, like positivity, negativity, neutral etc.
My question is, that maybe some of you has done this kind of thing already and can give me some recommendations about it? My version of it seems very slow and not very efficient (for me, at least).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try using `map`

Comment: @pissall can you specify, where exactly?